# How to delete the last document from firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

How does one delete the last document in a collection through firebase functions trigger?

I am trying to delete a document that I don't have a reference to. I just want to delete the last document using order by the descending and limiting to 1.

`admin.firestore().collection('notifications').orderBy("date",'desc').limit(1).delete();`

This is the error I get in the functions log.

"TypeError: admin.firestore(...).collection(...).orderBy(...).limit(...).delete is not a function
    at exports.updateUser.functions.firestore.document.onUpdate (/srv/index.js:219:97)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:119:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at 
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)"

Answer (score 0):

`admin.firestore().collection('notifications').orderBy("date",'desc').limit(1)` returns a [Query](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html) object.  As you can see from the linked API documentation, Query does not have a method called delete.

You will have to [get()](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/Query.html#get) the results of the query, look at the yielded [QuerySnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/firestore/latest/QuerySnapshot.html) to see if it matched a document, then delete the document using its reference.

You should go over the [documentation for Cloud Firestore queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries) in order to get familiar with the APIs.

Comment: Can you post the complete code? I am new to these promises and its giving me errors about not returning a promise or something